# Предлог об и обо

Tags: правописание

Скажите пожалуйста как правильно, "о мне", "обо мне"?

Answer (score 3):

Правильно "обо мне". О тут добавляется для благозвучия - согласитесь, две согласные подряд "об мне" звучат достаточно коряво.

Comment: Возможно, "об мне" (вместо "обо мне") звучит для русских также нелепо, как "блато" (вместо "болото"), "злато" (вместо "золото"), "крава" (вместо "корова"), "враны" (вместо "вороны"), "врата" (вместо "ворота"), "сраки" (вместо "сороки"), "брег" (вместо "берег") и т. д.

Comment: Все может быть, но мы же на старославянском не изъясняемся

Answer (score 3):

Вопрос был о другом: "о мне" или "обо мне"? вариант "об мне" для задавшего вопрос был заведомо неприемлем.
"Обо" действительно используется не вместо "об", а вместо "о". Причём только в нескольких случаях: обо мне, обо всех/всей/всём (есть ещё?)

Эта старая, благозвучная форма в современном языке, по-видимому, постепенно исчезает.

Насчёт того, когда использовать "о" и "об", думаю, вопросов нет. "Об" служит только для того, что избежать двух гласных подряд. При этом т.наз. йотированные гласные (мягкие) не требуют "об": "об армии", "об ужине", но "о еде", "о юристе".
(Устойчивые выражения, прошедшие через века, сохраняют старые формы: "рука об руку")

Answer (score 3):

В Интернете часто можно встретить дискуссии на тему предлогов О/ОБ/ОБО, но до конкретных выводов как-то дело не доходит. Думаю, что эмпирическое правило всё-таки можно составить следующим образом.

На выбор О/ОБ/ОБО влияют три фактора: фонетический, грамматический, традиционный.

А. Если существительное начинается на гласную (кроме йотированных), то пишем ОБ: сообщить об отъезде, удариться об асфальт. Это фонетический принцип.

Б. Прелоги участвуют в управлении В.п. или П.п. Для В.п. характерен предлог ОБ: удариться об дерево, об стену, а для П.п. - предлог О: думать о дереве, о стене. Это грамматический принцип.

В. Прелого ОБО используется в особых случаях, а именно с некоторыми местоимениями: обо мне, обо всех, обо всём (П.п.), обо что (В.п.), но: о тебе, о других, о чём. Это традиционный принцип. Возможно, эти исключения связаны с влиянием беглых гласных, например: меня - обо мне (вместо "об мене"), сравнить: тебя - о тебе.

Подобные  фонетические процессы мы наблюдаем в словах с приставками, например: обрыв - оборвать (приставка ОБО при отсутствии гласной в корне).

Comment: Насчёт винительного с "об" ... для меня звучит как просторечие.
Мне кажется, что падеж не влияет. Я всегда говорил "о стену", "о дерево", "о дверь". 

В просторечии можно ожидать "об" и в предложном: "думал об дереве". Или, помните у Бабеля: "думает об выпить хорошую стопку водки, об дать кому-нибудь по морде..."

Comment: "Лишь потом кто-то долго не сможет забыть, Как, шатаясь, бойцы об траву вытирали мечи.." (В. Цой).  "Бадья сорвалась, ударилась об стенку колодца и оторвала веревку" (Пушкин, Дубровский). И почему у Даля: "Корабль ударился о камень. Пуля об лоб его ударилась и отскочила"?  И почему в устойчивом выражении "рука об руку" пишется ОБ? Чем всё-таки различаются О и ОБ - семантикой или стилем? Как изменялись нормы со временем? Когда, с вашей точки зрения, предлог ОБ в В.п. стал просторечным? Мне кажется, все это надо понимать, чтобы вполне наслаждаться культурой речи.

Answer (score 0):

Вопрос был о другом: "о мне" или "обо мне"? вариант "об мне" для задавшего вопрос был заведомо неприемлем.
"Обо" действительно используется не вместо "об", а вместо "о". Причём только в нескольких случаях: обо мне, обо всех/всей/всём (есть ещё?)

Эта старая, благозвучная форма в современном языке, по-видимому, постепенно исчезает.

Насчёт того, когда использовать "о" и "об", думаю, вопросов нет. "Об" служит только для того, что избежать двух гласных подряд. При этом т.наз. йотированные гласные (мягкие) не требуют "об": "об армии", "об ужине", но "о еде", "о юристе".
(Устойчивые выражения, прошедшие через века, сохраняют старые формы: "рука об руку")